# yadcf custom_filter - how to find not null and not empty values?

Tags: javascript, yadcf

I want to filter on the column - a value that is not null and not empty.

```
 yadcf.init(table, [        
    {
        column_number: 4,
        filter_type: 'custom_func',
        custom_func: myCustomFilterFunction,
        data: [ {
            value: 'empty',
            label: 'Empty'
        },
            {
            value: 'notempty',
            label: 'NotEmpty'
            }
        ],
        filter_default_label: "All"
    }
]);  

function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
    var found;
    if (columnVal === '') {
        return true;
    }
    switch (filterVal) {
        case 'empty':
            found = columnVal.search(null);
            break;
        case 'notempty':
            found = columnVal.lenght > 0;
            break;
        default:
            found = 1;
            break;
    }
    if (found !== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Empty values filtering works .
But how to filter not empty and  not null values ? columnVal.lenght > 0 does not work

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle test page showing the problem

Comment: @Daniel I've created a jsfiddle test page: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Otonas/xpvt214o/840610/) . How to filter rows in which column "Description" is not empty or null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, here is a one way...

```
function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
    var found = false;
    debugger;
    switch (filterVal) {
        case 'empty':
            found = columnVal ? false : true;
            break;
        case 'notempty':
            found = columnVal ? true : false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return found;
}
```

[See working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/41zq3reL/9/)

Comment: Work like a charm ! Thanks for the answer and for the great plugin !